# Embedding scripts in html buttons

Tags: javascript, html, button

So, I'm a beginner programmer and figured I could do something short and fun. I made a short program in like 5 minutes, but I ran into a problem where I can't figure out, how to make a button that runs a said script when pressed (e.g. makes an alert with a random number in it)
Here's my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <Head>
        <h2>
        Random number Generator
        </h2>
    </Head>
    <body>
         <script src ="Script.js"></script>
        <button type="button" onclick="alert(randomNum)"> Generate! </button>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the script part here

```javascript
function randomNum(result, oneToHundred, randomNum) {
    let newNumber = Math.random()
    let oneToHundred = newNumber * 1000
    let result = Math.floor(oneToHundred)
    return result
};
alert(randomNum)
```

I just can't figure out how to make the button search for a script and run it when pressed. I tried to embed the script search to the onclick part, but i got a syntax error.

Comment: You are missing "()" in  onclick="alert(randomNum)"
it should be  onclick="alert(randomNum())"

Comment: For your next project, you might want to move from HTML's 'on...' properties (eg `<button id="my-btn" onClick="myFunction()"></button>`) to JS's [.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) method (eg `<button id="my-btn"></button> <script>let myBtn = document.getElementById("my-btn"); myBtn.addEventListener("click", myFunction)</script>` ). MDN likes this way bc it lets you add many listeners, gives finer control of listener timing, and works on any event target -- plus it keeps JS out of HTML. (I can write a better example if you like.)

Comment: If you could provide an example (preferably something even a brick wall would understand) that would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be simple example.

HTML file.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <Head>
        <h2>
        Random number Generator
        </h2>
    </Head>
    <body>
         <script src ="Script.js"></script>
        <button type="button" onclick="showMessage()"> Generate! </button>
    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript file.

```js
function showMessage() {
    alert("Hello friends, this is random number: " + Math.floor(Math.random() * 11));
}
```

Comment: So, if i understand it correctly, i was calling to alert for something that couldn't be? (I dunno if i'm getting it across correctly but i think i understand what i did wrong) Anyways it's working now and thanks for your help